# Mathematical formula for a pattern

Tags: pattern-recognition

I was cooking and saw a chart of temperature vs cooking time like so:

1. $154\mathrm{F}$ - $36$ hours
2. $164\mathrm{F}$ - $18$ hours
3. $174\mathrm{F}$ - $9$ hours

Basically for every $10\mathrm{F}$ increase in temperature, cooking time is halved. Now I'm thinking, there must be a **formula** to easily figure out if temperature is $x$, then cooking time is $y$. Or vice-versa, if I want to cook it for $y$, then I should set temperature to $x$.

I was racking my brain trying to figure this out. I feel like it should be obvious :(

Comment: @Stefan: I disagree with your edit. Unit symbols such as kg, N, and °F are never set in italics.

Comment: @RahulNarain: You're absolutely right. I re-edited it - thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$x = 154 +10n \implies y = \dfrac{36}{2^n}$$
Hence,
$$y = \dfrac{36}{2^{(x-154)/10}}$$

Comment: How elegant! Thank you!

Comment: @pixelfreak: And of course $x=154+10\log_2(36/y)$.